# How to remove a core data class completely from an xcode project?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a core data class that doesn't need to be saved in core data anymore, it will be kept in memory now. What is the right way to delete it from xcdatamodeld and also delete the core data files associated with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the .xcdatamodeld file, press on the entity you wish to delete, and just press the delete button on the keyboard. This will delete all the classes that were automatically generated by XCode

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that OP should clean the build folder and rebuild the project to remove any references to the generated class(es)

Comment: Thanks guys... the codegen is manual, do I just delete the files manually after deleting the entity from the xcdatamodel file?

Comment: Yes, that is enough